# using pino multistream with synchronous logging

Tags: node.js, curl, pinojs

from what I understand, Pino (v 7.5.1) by default does sync logging. From the docs

> In Pino's standard mode of operation log messages are directly written to the output stream as the messages are generated with a blocking operation.

I am using `pino.multistreams` like so

```js
const pino = require('pino')
const pretty = require('pino-pretty')
const logdir = '/Users/punkish/Projects/z/logs'

const streams = [
    {stream: fs.createWriteStream(`${logdir}/info.log`, {flags: 'a'})},
    {stream: pretty()},
    {level: 'error', stream: fs.createWriteStream(`${logdir}/error.log`, {flags: 'a'})},
    {level: 'debug', stream: fs.createWriteStream(`${logdir}/debug.log`, {flags: 'a'})},
    {level: 'fatal', stream: fs.createWriteStream(`${logdir}/fatal.log`, {flags: 'a'})}
]
```

Strangely, Pino is behaving asynchronously. I have a `curl` operation that is outputting out of sequence (before earlier events that are using `log.info`)

```js
log.info('1')
.. code to do 1 something

log.info('2')
.. code to do 2 something

log.info('3')
.. code to do 3 something

const execSync = require('child_process').execSync
execSync(curl --silent --output ${local} '${remote}')
```

and my `console` output is

```sh
1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 39.5M  100 39.5M    0     0   108M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  113M
2
3
```

this is a bit annoying and confusing. Maybe this is not the fault of Pino, and maybe `curl` is causing the problem. But if I replace pino logging with `console.log` then the order is as expected. So it seems the problem is with Pino behaving asynchronously. How can I go back to synchronous logging?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you accepted the answer :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your suggestion works. (sorry for the long delay in response)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to call `pino.destination({...})` to create a [SonicBoom](https://github.com/pinojs/sonic-boom) output stream: a pino-specific alternative to `fs.createWriteStream`.  The `SonicBoom` options have a boolean property `sync`.  You also need the `sync` option in `pretty({...})`.

```
const pino = require('pino')
const pretty = require('pino-pretty')
const logdir = '/Users/punkish/Projects/z/logs'

const createSonicBoom = (dest) => 
  pino.destination({dest: dest, append: true, sync: true})

const streams = [
    {stream: createSonicBoom(`${logdir}/info.log`)},
    {stream: pretty({
      colorize: true,
      sync: true,
    })},
    {level: 'error', stream: createSonicBoom(`${logdir}/error.log`)},
    {level: 'debug', stream: createSonicBoom(`${logdir}/debug.log`)},
    {level: 'fatal', stream: createSonicBoom(`${logdir}/fatal.log`)}
]
```

Test:

```
const log = pino({ level: 'info' }, pino.multistream(streams))

console.log('Before-Fatal')
log.fatal('Fatal')
log.error('Error')
log.warn('Warn')
console.log('After-Warn, Before-Info')
log.info('Info')
console.log('After-Info')
```

Output:

```
Before-Fatal
[1234567890123] FATAL (1234567 on host): Fatal
[1234567890127] ERROR (1234567 on host): Error
[1234567890127] WARN (1234567 on host): Warn
After-Warn, Before-Info
[1234567890128] INFO (1234567 on host): Info
After-Info
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like using `pino.multistream` (or multiple transports, which seem to have the same effect as multistream) automatically forces pino to behave asynchronously. There is no way around it. Since synchronous logging is more impt for me than speed (in this project), I will look for an alternative logging solution

Comment: I saw the Github issue where the maintainer told you this about `pino.multistream`, but it's not true.  See my answer.  I think it was a communication issue (he assumed you were not using `pino.destination`).  It totally depends on the underlying individual streams.

Comment: Last point: the `transport` module performs logging in worker threads and is therefore always async, whereas `multistream` uses the task queue when operating asynchronously.